# Passing Parameters to CloudFormation via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameters, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to implement a CF stack via the CLI. I enter the following command:

`aws cloudformation create-stack --region $region --stack-name this-stacks-name --template-body file://cf_templates/this-stacks-yaml.yml --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --parameters ParameterKey=ReplicationS3BucketName,ParameterValue=$bucketname`

I receive the following error:

`An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Parameter values specified for a template which does not require them.`

This is the relevant section of the template:

```
Parameters:
  ReplicationS3BucketName:
    Description: "Parameter for custom S3 bucket name
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*"
Resources:
  ReplicationS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub ${ReplicationS3BucketName}-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: AES256
      AccessControl: Private
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You are probably using the wrong template.

Comment: Thank you. I was annoyed at this comment, then I decided to look deeper.

Right template but in the wrong folder, lol.

Comment: It happens. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by using wrong template file in the command line.